# Glasses referred to as "it", i.e. singular, by a native speaker of English

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I've been taught that *glasses* (as in *spectacles* i.e. visual aid) are plural. It's also confirmed by numerous hits on the google ([reference 1](https://www.grammar-monster.com/plurals/plural_of_glasses.htm),
[reference 2](https://www.quora.com/Is-glasses-plural-or-singular),
[reference 3](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/glasses)). In case the multiplicity of the equipment needs to be explicitly emphasized, one can say *five **pairs** of glasses* or simply reformulate in an appropriate way.

However, in the movie *Come As You Are* (about 45'15" in), the following dialogue takes place.

> **A**: I lost my glasses.
> **B**: It's right here. It's right here.
> **A**: I lost my fucking glasses!
> **B**: It's around your neck.

All the characters are native English speakers and there's no reason to make a grammatical error in the plot. The movie is subtitled so it can't be my hearing impediment. I even checked with two alternative sources for subs, all with consistent result.

Naturally, I expected ***they're** right here* and ***they're** around your neck*. What's up with that?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings yes, of course it's a good question.  But the top-ticked answer for example is confusing.   The only thing it should say in an answer is "It is a mistake."  (Certainly everything written in that answer is correct and well-explained.  But if a non-native speaker asks *"I saw color spelled covor in The Times?"* the only thing to tell them in answer is *"It's a typo"*.  Maybe one could *also* then include a dissertation on the history of spelling or such!  But for clarity the basic, bold, clear answer needed is "oh, that's wrong".)

Comment: @Fattie Feel free to write a new answer that just says "It is a mistake", though I remain unconvinced that it'll be seen as being very competitive.

Comment: @Fattie As far I see, there's only one answer provided so, by definition, it will be the top-ticked one, won't it? Nerdy logic aside, I kind of appreciate a bit longer explanation because it creates the notion of really understanding the issue being asked, whereas simple *nope, it's a typo*, might be perceived as too shallow and not fully understanding the circumstances around the situation. Also, I disagree that it's a common mistake of the same magnitude as most others. I've never seen that in NSE but notice other kinds of errors.

Comment: PS, I did not say it is a common mistake.  (That particular grouping of words has probably never been used before.)  I said that that type of mistake, indeed *any* mistake in English, is extremely common.  English is *staggeringly, just amazingly* loose and (in the current era, in all English-speaking regions) spoken language at an almost unbelievably low level; erudition is non-existent.  Folks from other regions really tend to "not believe" the amazingly low level of English (both spoken/written) in this era - !

Comment: @Fattie As for your PS, I see where you're coming from. However, I'd like to draw a freaking like somewhere and declassify what you refer to as *amazingly low level of English* from being English. It's Jibrish, perhaps resembling and inspired by English. But to be English, it has to sustain a certain linguistic quality, in my opinion. Because **trying** to speak English **isn't** speaking English. Just as me trying to shed some kilos of my fat ass doesn't mean my ass is anywhere of being less fat. But I do see your point and agree with your observation, just disputing the classification.

Comment: Konrad, my friend, it's **gibberish**. There are likely non-standard speech phenomena from native speakers all the time but this one (it for them) is simply extremely unlikely. "Where are my shorts, Mom? Did you put **it** in the dryer**? [buzzer] Who would even say that??

Comment: @Lambie I can't help wonder if people make the mistake because there are other "pluralities" treated as singular. ***It was** great new**s**.* ***It's** mean**s** to an end.*

Comment: @KonradViltersten theorizing why, in one particular instance, a mistake is made in spoken English, would be like theorizing why, in one particular instance, a politician lied, a hooker charged money or a Beagle was hungry.  :)   Such (embarrassing) errors are *totally ubiquitous*.   Regarding Americans etc, no, you're wrong - the compound phrase "English speakers/ing/etc" is a very common unit (including in the US, Canada, Aus. etc).  "the English-speaking world" etc.  (It's the English translation of "francophone") (If that makes sense :)  )

Comment: No, Konrad. That is simply not the case: glasses, shorts, pants, trousers, etc. are third person plural always. It simply is not wired into the brain as anything other than "they". So, it could only be a very odd slip of the tongue.

Comment: NSEs? National Stock Exchanges? Navier-Stokes equations? Non-sovereign entities...?

Comment: @Lambie Oh, I do agree. I'm not saying that *news* is plural on the same conditions as *glasses*. I'm just speculating that some people might confuse the ending "s" and (incorrectly) believe that both are plural, in some way.

Comment: @ilkkachu NSE = Native Speaker of English, as I explained in an earlier comment. Apparently, it's challenged by an alternative acronym.

Comment: @KonradViltersten, I can see no earlier comment where that acronym would have been explained, or the words "Native Speaker of English" written. I tried to look. And I tried to figure out how it fits in the context, but couldn't come up with what it would have been an abbreviation for. The point here is that one shouldn't assume all acronyms are familiar to every reader, but instead open them the first time they're mentioned. Or just write "native speaker" instead in a case like this.

Comment: **It was great news**. and. "It's *a means* to an end" are not the same thing **at all**.

Comment: @Lambie I never claimed those were the same thing semantically. I only used two phrases containing a noun ending with "s", which may appear to someone unfamiliar with English as a plural, whereas it's not. Such a person might due to their ignorance assume that the ending "s" is pluralizing the word and not consider verifying that assumption.

Comment: @ilkkachu I did elaborate the acronym but it seems that the comment has been removed (along with the comment asking for said elaboration), so your question is reasonable. However, as far I've been informed, NSE was a well-established acronym and as such, doesn't call for introduction. (Note that I might be misinformed but I'm explaining the lack of introduction.) If I use *NSA*, I won't introduce the term as I'm assuming it's well-known. There might be someone who hasn't heard it before and I'll gladly explain it but introducing it just in case seems inefficient.

Comment: @ilkkachu So given that it's a well-established term (i.e. *NSE*, not *NSA*), I see no need to define it in case there's some user who hasn't seen it. When I saw it the first time, I asked and got it explained. No complaining about pre-defining it due to my ignorance. Now, based on another comment, it seems that the acronym *NES* is suggested to be more widely established, so I might have been misinformed. In such case, my apologies.

Comment: @eddiekal I see your edit. Would you care to elaborate? I've been informed on numerous occasions that *NSE* is an accepted term, especially in the context of this particular community. And while there might be some users who aren't familiar with the abbreviation, it's easily googlable to find out. And there are tons of other terms that a learner of English might not be familiar with.

Comment: Never seen it used. Also there was a comment you might have seen that'd only existed for a few hours before being deleted: "What's NSE? Native speaker of English?" That comment, despite its short life span, garnered 7 likes. That says a lot about the unpopularity of that abbreviation. On top of all that, abbreviations are not encouraged across the SE network, especially in the posts. Especially ELL as you yourself have said learners of English are not familiar with lots of terms. Posts are not SMS texts and should avoid abbreviations and jargon.

Comment: @EddieKal Thanks for the explanation. It seems to be opinionated so I'll let it stay as is, to avoid "flame war", hehe. That said, I need to point out hat upvotes for a comment don't necessarily mean it was appreciated (no down-option e.g.). Also, you used *SE* and *ELL* which were introduced in the context of this site because they're convenient and needed. I believe we **should** introduce NSE here for the same reason. Lastly, not knowing an abbreviation isn't a reason to avoid a term. It's a reason to learn it. (Within reason, of course.)

Comment: I've seen NNS (non-native speaker) quoted a number of times but not NSE. I've also seen the scronym OED on both English sites  and on several occasions edited to actually write its full name at least once. Explaining an acronym is an act of courtesy.

Comment: Is NSE really that easy to [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=nse&oq=NSE&aqs=chrome.0.0j46j0l2j0i457j0l4j46.2149j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Admittedly, I get a less relevant search results than I did before, when I initially encountered that term. So I stand corrected. Your acronym, OED, was at the top, though. On the other hand, ELL was not. Difficult to say what the best practice. I still maintain that NSE is a term that's so fundamental to this community's focus area that is should be introduced and gain spread. However, the suggestion to spell it out at least once is very wise. I'll try to remember and apply it.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

This is a typical mistake, or piece of jibberish.

Such mistakes are ***completely ubiquitous*** in both published spoken and published written English, in this era.

It's one example of a billion.

(There is ***absolutely no special significance***, whatsoever, about the taxonomy, origin or mechanics of this particular fuck-up.)

It is kindly described as "a slip of the tongue" or more bluntly "illiterate, ignorant, uneducated screenwriting".

Comment: "Ow, eez ye-ooa san, is e? Wal, fewd dan y' de-ooty bawmz a mather should, eed now bettern to spawl a pore gel's flahrzn than ran awy atbaht pyin. Will ye-oo py me f'them?" Clearly George Bernard Shaw was illiterate.

Comment: I don't understand why so heavy downvote on this. In fact, I can't see a reason to have any downs at all. I'll +1 it to counter the push-down as it seems way to harsh for an answer that is well-formulated and actually answering the question.

Comment: @KonradViltersten This answer is pretty rude to the screenwriter and doesn't allow for deliberately using poor grammar in dialog for character development or any other reason why there might be non-standard grammar besides the screenwriter being "illiterate, ignorant, uneducated".

Comment: @user3067860 I believe that you're mistaken, possibly reading into the text more than there's actually said. If you, kindly please, re-read the text, there's nothing there referencing the screenwriter. Fattie complains about people making said mistake, among a lot others and suggests that the screenwriter might skillfully have caught that linguistic sloppiness of contemporary culture. At least that's how I see the last sentence. I also disagree with Fattie that it's such a common mistake, the one considered in this question of plural *it's*.

Comment: @KonradViltersten "illiterate, ignorant, uneducated screenwriting"... I don't see how that's about anyone other than the screenwriter, and calling someone illiterate, ignorant, or uneducated is pretty rude. Especially when this answer doesn't offer any other potential reason (like poor grammar in dialog for characterization or even multiple changes during rewrites leading to unnoticed errors).

Comment: @user3067860 Ah, I see how you interpreted the last sentence. If Fattie's intention was aligned with it, then I agree there's certain rudeness. I'm not sure your view is the one that Fattie intended, though. I'm thinking, if I say *it was an aggressive screenwriting*, I don't evaluate the screenwriter themselves but rather the achieved intonation conveyed by the text. Then, I just swap the epithet for *ignorant* and tada! I understood them as that screenwriting was done well and expressing the illiteracy etc. of the contemporary lack of eloquence. But I might very well be mistaken there.

Comment: @KonradViltersten I think from the number of down votes that I'm not the only one reading it that way. For me, it refers to *how* the writer wrote, not necessarily the effect they achieved, although sometimes they are intertwined. But you might have "good screenwriting" about bad characters and "bad screenwriting" about good characters (if you search for good/bad screenwriting you'll see what I mean).

Comment: @user3067860 I do not disagree. You have an excellent point. I just have such an aversion towards downvotes. I've seen cases when people downvote because there are already downvotes. Not saying it's the case here. Just said aversion... I prefer not to upvote instead. But, like I said, you're probably right in your interpretation. Let's leave it at that.

Answer (score 16):

"Glasses" are always plural, unless you specifically refer to them as "*a pair* of glasses" which acts as a collective noun.

For example:

- **Some** glasses.
- **A pair** of glasses.
- **This** is my **pair** of glasses.
- **These** are my glasses.

Of course, you can refer to *multiple pairs* in the plural.

I have to conclude that the dialogue you quoted is *wrong*. As the first person referred to them as "my glasses" not a *pair* of glasses, the second person should have followed and said, "*they* are round your neck".

If this were a real-life situation, I'd think that the second person just viewed the pair of glasses, along with the chain or whatever was holding the glasses around the person's neck, as a singular item. As a written piece of dialogue in a movie, I'm more inclined to think it was either a mistake, or more likely a deliberate use of bad English to imply a lack of language skill by the character.

Comment: "Three young men with disabilities hit the road with a jaded nurse driver to a brothel in Montreal catering to people with special needs." Dialog is as quoted on a script site I found. Agree about the chain/cord possibility.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I don't think he refers to the chain/cord, as the first two lines aren't referring to anything else but the missing object in question, i.e. the glasses. Based on how sure the responders seem to be in combination with my experience, I'll call a grammar mistake here. I just didn't expected one to be possible on such a basic level. To be honest, I was certain about the grammar and worried about that being a slang or some kind of colloquial expression. But that seems not to be the case.

Comment: @KonradViltersten - this is movie dialogue representing energetic informal conversation between people who are not students of grammar. I can fully believe that this is how some people talk.

Comment: I personally have never heard anyone talk this way (I'm British). I suppose it is possible. Is the character in the movie a native English speaker?

Comment: People sometimes make mistakes in their spoken grammar. Even really bad ones.

Comment: @chasly - these are Americans, and not Standard US English speakers, near the Canadian border. They are not gringo types either.

Comment: A glance at the cast list shows that not all characters are meant to speak text-book US Standard English.

Comment: From the amount of "then" I see used on a regular basis instead of "than", it seems that many people in real life indeed don't speak text-book English... now indeed with something so obviously plural, it seems more of a silly thing to do.

Comment: @LaurentS. - what you 'see' is a spelling error. This does not mean they _say_ 'then' when they mean 'than'.

Comment: @chasly-reinstateMonica As stated in the title, yes - each participant is NSE.

Comment: @KonradViltersten "each participant is NSE" - for some value of "NSE".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey You are completely wrong. (For some value of "wrong", that is.)   :)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Just to make sure - the previous comment is a friendly joke not a sarcastic and rude come-back. Technically speaking, of we denote *correct* and assign it to the spelling *wrong*, being right will be *to be **wrong***. Of course, extremely confusing conduct.